# Java Citation Generator Library

Tags: java, generator

Do you know any for Harvard/Chicago/Latex/etc. style citations?

Comment: There is a connotea-java on Google code, which doesn't seem to be a general purpose library.

Answer (score 0):

I found [JavaTeX](http://www.monperrus.net/martin/running+tex+on+a+java+virtual+machine) and [jtex(Java latex library)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtex/) and this [paper](http://www.tug.org/TUG99-web/pdf/murphy.pdf) maybe helpful to you

Comment: It doesn't help. I need a very simple library, having author name, article/book title and a few other metadata outputs its citation string is a predefined format.